# How the pass Jython modules to wsadmin tool

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, wsadmin

I'm using the Websphere 8 Thin Client to connect to my remote WAS instance.

I'm trying to import some Jyton files by passing `python.path` to `wsadmin` but it cannot find them. I keep hitting `NameError` on the Jython class.

```
C:\MyThinClient>wsadmin -host <ipaddress> -port 8880 -lang jython -javaoption "-Dpython.path=C:/MyThinClient/Jython/"
```

> WASX7209I: Connected to process "server1" on node XYZNode01 using SOAP
>   connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess WASX7031I: For
>   help, enter: "print Help.help()"
>   wsadmin>AdminApplication.listApplications() WASX7015E: Exception
>   running command: "AdminApplication.listApplications()"; exception
>   information:  com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
>   Traceback (innermost last):   File "", line 1, in ? NameError:
>   AdminApplication

The path passed contains the AdminApplication.py file.
I've tried passing the Jython path with back-slash and forward-slash but no joy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try with option -Dwsadmin.script.libraries, like below. It worked for me

C:\MyThinClient>wsadmin -host  -port 8880 -lang jython -javaoption "-Dwsadmin.script.libraries==C:/MyThinClient/Jython/"